# Does comma only applied to console.log in javascript to concatenate variables with the strings?

Tags: javascript

kindly enlighten me as I am new to javascript. I have sample 1 and 2 below and I wonder why sample 2 can't display the right expected result when keyword "return" is being used. I know plus(+) sign could solve the issue in question, just wondering when to used comma(,) for concatenation in javascript when it comes to variables.

```
sample-1
var person = {
  firstName: "John",
  lastName : "Smith",
  fullName : function() {
    console.log("my name is ",this.firstName +" ",this.lastName);
  }
}
person.fullName(); //my name is  John  Smith

sample-2
var person = {
  firstName: "John",
  lastName : "Smith",
  fullName : function() {
    return "my name is ",this.firstName +" ",this.lastName;
  }
}
person.fullName(); //"Smith"
```

Comment: The comma operator evaluates each of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the last operand.

Comment: @kemotoe except in a function call when it separates different arguments...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commas *inside* the parentheses marking a function call separate the argument expressions. Outside, as in your `return` statement, they're the "comma operator".

So the magic that `console.log()` does is just based on code in that function that explicitly looks at all arguments you pass it.

The `return` is basically equivalent to

```
"my name is ";
this.firstName + " ";
return this.lastName;
```

The commas in your sample split the overall expression up into three pieces, and each piece is separately evaluated. The overall value of `a, b, c` is the value of `c` alone.

Answer (score 2):

With

```
    console.log("my name is ",this.firstName +" ",this.lastName);
```

you pass several arguments to the `console.log` function. It works just like any plain function call. The number of arguments for `console.log` is more or less arbitrary, the function will know what to do with them (kind of like `Math.max`).

That

```
    return "my name is ",this.firstName +" ",this.lastName;
```

doesn't return several values (looks like it is going to return `this.lastName`). A function can return a single value, or no value at all. You want to concat the above to a single string, you must do it differently. With `+`, for example.

Comment: The `return` is not *incorrect*, it just won't do what the OP expects. If it were invalid syntax the OP wouldn't have noticed the strange return value because the code would not have run.

Comment: `it is simply incorrect syntax` it is *correct* syntax. But the computer does what you've told it to do, not what you want it to do.