# Concatenation or comma in JavaScript? What is the difference and how to choose?

Tags: javascript, concatenation

I recently started learning JavaScript and I have a question. In one example, I saw that `console.log("Example"+"one");` so we can output multiple words by separating them by concatenation. And I saw `console.log("Example","one");` so we can just separate them by commas, and it outputs the same thing.  But what is the difference in their purpose? The fact that when concatenating, you need to provide for spaces yourself? Which method do you use more often and why?

Comment: Related: [Why comma ' , ' and plus ' + ' log the console output in different pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33339688/why-comma-and-plus-log-the-console-output-in-different-pattern) and [Does comma only applied to console.log in javascript to concatenate variables with the strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55709288/does-comma-only-applied-to-console-log-in-javascript-to-concatenate-variables-wi)

Comment: And note this really only applies to console methods, there are plenty of other functions where passing one or two arguments will do completely different things.

Comment: ^ this does not even apply to console methods. This applies to this special case where you're only dealing with strings. But how often is it the case that you log only strings?

Comment: @Thomas good point, the result of coercing to string for concatenation is likely different to logging the actual value.